# make dt and dd the same height to apply a background color on dt

Tags: html, css

I have this markup:

```
<dl class="item_tabs_details">
    <dt>Lot Size</dt>
    <dd>324 sq. meters</dd>

    <dt>Baths</dt>
    <dd>2</dd>

    <dt>Full Description</dt>
    <dd>
        <p>
        House & Lot for Sale/Rent, 4BR, 1165sqm. PHP65M/200K/MO. (Pasig) Beautiful
        house with 4 bedrooms, den/office, entertainment room, covered lanai, swimming
        pool and manicured garden.
        </p>
    </dd>
</dl>
```

using this style:

```
dl.item_tabs_details dt, dl.item_tabs_details dd{
    float:left;
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}
dl.item_tabs_details dt{
    width:130px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    color: #000;
}

dl.item_tabs_details dd{
    width:760px;
    min-height: 12px;
}
```

if dd spans more than 1 line, I want the dt's height to be the same as the dd so that I can apply a background color to it without having some "holes".

Comment: i think this is because you are setting padding to 10px;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't an "easy CSS fix" here.

In this case, I would probably use a `table`, because that does look somewhat like tabular data (and it makes solving your problem *really* easy).

http://jsfiddle.net/UvPGG/

```
<table class="item_tabs_details" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Lot Size</th>
    <td>324 sq. meters</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Baths</th>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Full Description</th>
    <td>House &amp; Lot for Sale/Rent, 4BR, 1165sqm. PHP65M/200K/MO. (Pasig) Beautiful house with 4 bedrooms, den/office, entertainment room, covered lanai, swimming pool and manicured garden.</td>
  </tr>
</table>

.item_tabs_details {
    width: 890px
}
.item_tabs_details td, .item_tabs_details th {
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    vertical-align: top
}
.item_tabs_details th {
    width: 130px;
    background: #ccc;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: normal
}
```

Comment: Hey, someone actually agrees that tables are fine for this case :) I'm kinda undecided myself...

Comment: Yeah, it's borderline. I was considering posting an answer with the same HTML, but with a `130x1` `repeat-y` background image on the `dl`, but `table`s won in the end.

Comment: hey, thanks for this. I used tables before but could not find a way to make <th> horizontal. also, +1 for the scope attribute, it's the first time I've seen that.

Comment: I'm against tables for this because they're way too restrictive when it comes to responsive design, which is probably a bigger concern now than when this answer was first posted.