# How to make dt and dd tag to have the same height for background?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249842/make-dt-and-dd-the-same-height-to-apply-a-background-color-on-dt) there isn't an easy way to solve this and just use the table. But even so is there any way to make it work? My problem is I have a background for dt but when dd have more contents than dt, its height remains the same. How do I make both of them to have the same height? I'm thinking of getting their height in jquery but it seems a bit complex to do that. I'm a beginner in jquery so I'm not sure if it will work out. Anyway, I don't want the `negative margin` and `padding` because I need the dl to be `overflow: visible` because of a dropdown.

Original

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/buzjby59/)**

With `negative margin` and `padding`

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/mnwhmec3/2/)**

In any case, I don't want it to be margin-padding combo at all cost. But as for converting it to table I am open to it if that is the only way to fix this. Please give me an insight of how I should fix this. Thank you very much!

Comment: in my case, I use chrome and saw same result with these two fiddles.

Comment: sorry I didn't get to save the last one.

Answer (score 3):

May b it will be helpful:

Check Here: 
https://jsfiddle.net/buzjby59/2/

```
<dl>
  <dt>Term A</dt>
  <dd>Definition A1</dd>
  <dd>Definition A2</dd>
  <dd>Definition A3</dd>
  <dd>Definition A4</dd>
</dl>
<dl>
  <dt>Term B</dt>
  <dd>Definition B1</dd>
  <dd>Definition B2</dd>
  <dd>Definition B3</dd>
</dl>

body {
    margin: 0;
}
dl {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    margin:0 0 15px;
}
dt {
    background: #999999;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 80px;
}
dd {
    background: #3399ff;
    margin-left: 0;
    display:block;
}
dt:after, dd:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: It's not ideal to have to have a separate DL for each term.

Answer (score 0):

There are jquery plugins for that, for instance this one: http://css-tricks.github.io/Equalizer/

Comment: Ah yes but as much as possible I don't want to use plugins.

Comment: In that case you can use display: table, see this tutorial: http://demo.hongkiat.com/css-equal-height/

Comment: Or even simpler, you can add the background-color to the <dl>. Will that work for you?

Comment: Tried it but unfortunately no. :(

Comment: You have to remove the floats though, and set display: table to <dl> and <dd>, and display: table-cell to <dt>

Answer (score 0):

Please see this:

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/EdmondWang/3eur6dqz/)`See fiddle`

I use the display:table.
Not sure If it is what you need.

Comment: Add the code to the answer, in addition to the fiddle.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It simply works and answer the question. +1

Answer (score 0):

Well, it really depends on what you are trying to do, in the final run.
Because if there isn't a simple way to do it, then there is some work-arounds to accomplish the purpose.
A simple way to set up the background would be to just use this:

```
dl {
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    background:#999999;
}
```

But, I suggest you change your code a little bit to include different type of tags, like Div